# Verify that a certificate belongs to a given user

Tags: client-certificates, certificate

How can I (or, is it possible) to verify that a user certificate belongs to a given user?

For example, in an e-Voting system I want to prohibit that an user A who has a certificate C1 votes for other people.

How can I detect that when someone presents C1 and tries to vote as, say, user B, that this is the wrong combination, and deny him the right to vote?

Is it even possible to do this with certificates, or should I use additionally an username and password to confirm identity?

Comment: Use proper terms. There's no such thing as "SSL certificate". There exist X.509 certificates, some of which can be used for securing SSL protocol. But they are not SSL certificates at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the subject field of the X509 certificate to identify the person. That cannot be forged, given that you fully trust the certificate issuer.

If person B has access to person A's certificate, he/she could certainly vote at his/her place, but you cannot do much at this stage (added a password? Who guarantees that B does not know that as well?).

A severe issue is that in many (if not all) democratic voting systems, vote is secret. By having the user identify him/herself via a certificate and possibly storing identity info in their session, you are failing to honour this basic constraint.

If the application is critical (i.e. a real, regional/national e-Voting system), then:

1. you should consider using X509 physical tokens, a.k.a. smart cards, to securely store voter certificate and private key.
2. you **SHOULD NOT** seek advice on StackOverflow. Hire a committed and competent security consultant.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a real application, it's for educational purposes only. I want to better grasp the intricacies of SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

When you use client SSL certificates, the certificate fingerprint is checked by the web server, which uniquely authenticates the user. In this type of scenario, you would not have a typical login form, since the server can authenticate your browser without it.

The voting step would only occur **after** the user/browser is properly authenticated. *This does not necessarily mean that you bound the session to a username*. You just need to bind it to a unique identifier.

Using an additional authentication step (username/password, TOTP, ...) is possible, and may be desired, but authentication should only succeed if all those steps succeed.

Note that the vast majority of sites do not currently use client certificates for authentication. It's a very uncommon practice nowadays.